# Can ScalaMock3 mock java.lang.Thread.sleep

Tags: scala, scalamock

Is there a way to mock sleep and set an expectation on it?

```
class Foo {
  def func = {
    Thread.sleep(100)
  } 
}
```

For example, in Ruby, I'd just add the stub to Thread.  But with Scalamock, I'm not sure how to inject that mock into the class.